# Subscriber Key Migration

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm attempting to upgrade from V2 connector to V5 and I'm having issue with understanding the Subscriber Key Migration. If we need to enable subscriber keys in order to begin the connector process, is this something that must be done only through support or am I required to learn API for this functionality?